# Writing a OOPHP Templating System

Tags: php, html, oop

Hey guys so this is the first time that I've written OOPHP and I am trying to use it as a templating system. So far I have

```
<?php
   class templates{
      public $username = ;

      public $header =;

      public $user_bar =;

      public $user_info =;
    }
?>
```

I've written in JavaScript Object Orientation though PHP is some what different. Question is how would I define an entire HTML section as one of these public objects? So that like so

```
 <?php 
    include_once("template_class.php");
    $temp = new templates();
 ?>

   <div class="user_basic">
       <?php echo->$temp->$user_info ?>
   </div>
```

Which then should parse a long HTML structure with other PHP variables in it... EX:

```
   <div id="sidebar" class="clearfix">
        <div id="">
            <button class="profile">Follow</button>
        </div>
        <div id="profile-header-picture">
            <img src="$user_image" />
        </div>
        <ul id="profile-header-user-stats" class="clearfix gray-menu">
            <li><p class="w700">40</p><p class="s13 gray">Followers</p></li>
            <li><p class="w700">78</p><p class="s13 gray">Following</p></li>
            <li><p class="w700 tooltip" title="$user_level_title">$user_level</p><p class="s13 gray">Level</p></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="profile-header-menu" class="s14 w400 gray-menu">
            <li class="selected"><a href="#" class="block w700">News Feed</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="block"><span>Challenges</span><span class="green">$_challenges_count</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="block">Statistics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="block">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="block">Videos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Now I know inside my templates system I'll probably have to define another query to get such variables

EX:

```
 $user_level_title = echo->$user->$title;
 $user_level = echo->$user->$level;
 $user_image = echo->$user->$image;
 $_challenges_count = echo->$user->$challenges_count;
```

How do I get the entire HTML structure in a public object? Does it need to be on one line, or does it take like JavaScript where I'll need to concatenate an array?

Looking for the best options on how to write a simple templating system so I don't have to include hundreds of php files.

Comment: Are you aware that `echo->$user->$title` is not valid PHP code? `echo $user->title` is actually

Comment: Oh ok ;) Yeah I should have said I'm not very experienced in PHP at all haha. Especially using the `->`. And I was thinking should I just do 
`public $header = include_once('header.php'); `

?

Comment: The `->` is used for accessing methods and attributes on an Object `echo $temp->user_info;` for example. You better use a method `getHeader()` for example, which returns the content of the `header.php` with `file_get_contents('header.php')`. Your method then looks something like this: `public function getHeader(){ return file_get_contents('header.php'); }`. You can access that function through `echo $temp->getHeader();`.

Comment: Ok let me try that out and see how it feels and looks. I like keep code clean and organized. So that's why I'm being a stickler about this.

Comment: Works perfectly. So now I can add multiple classes to that and public objects so that it'll be nice and clean. Quick question though I still need help with getting contents further deeply nested in the templates.php can I `include_once()` inside that?

Comment: @EasyBB , you probably will want to read this: http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up on it

Comment: @tereško That was actually wonderful to read. Thanks

Comment: As f_g_c() is not what I am looking for as it returns a string. It needs to be able to parse PHP that is within the code as well. I changed code to -- `public function getHeader(){ return $header = include_once('header.php'); }`